# In Android Studio, cannot delete unnecessary folder

Tags: android, android-studio

Say I want to remove the 'facebook' folder. When I right click on that folder, and go to refactor, the delete option is grayed out. But I want to delete it. I also tried selecting the folder and pressing delete on the keyboard. Still could not delete.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Delete via command line? Delete via GUI(explorer.exe or w/e OS you are on)?

Comment: I don't want to potentially mess up the project. And also, if the IDE does not let me delete it, there might be a good reason to not delete it (I don't know what that good reason is)

Answer (score 10):

You can switch to Project and delete it.

Here is my example. I have created a JNI module (the highlighted folder) in my project:

[image]

Now you just need to switch from "Android" to "Project" and click delete:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reason might be that the `facebook` (sdk) folder is part of your project (in used in your project) now and Android Studio doesn't let you do that.

If so, I am sure it will be in the `settings.gradle` as follow.

```
include ':facebook'
```

and in your app folder `build.gradle`, at the below, there's the `dependencies` and the folder would be included as follow.

`compile project(':facebook')`

Remove those lines and try removing it.

You can manually remove the folder as well but it's a good practice you remove it from the IDE because the IDE will check whether it's safe to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> Open Module Settings

[image]

Select your Module Folder and delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux but the project is located in a driver you mounted from windows, move it to the Linux local file system, I just figured it out when I was in this situation. Good luck.